# ¿Cómo llenar y asignarle un array al valor de un Input con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trato de asignarle un valor array a un input que saco de otros inputs para después capturarlo con PHP.

**- El input:**

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <label for="stock">Precio</label>
    <input type="text" name="precioc" class="form-control" id="precioc">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <label for="cant">PRUEBA</label>
    <input type="select" name="pcom[]" class="form-control" id="pcom">
</div>
```

**- La función que debería de agregar en el JavaScript:**

```
function agregar()
{
    precio_compra = $("#precioc").val();

    $("#pcom").val(precio_compra);

}
```

> La idea general es tratar de llenar el vector con una función agregar,
> para después obtener dichos valores con un Submit, pero como esta,
> solo captura el ultimo valor.

Comment: Estoy 100% seguro de que el input type select no existe. Lo más fácil sería tener un input type text y en el back recibir una cadena de texto que puedes dividirla por comas o en el submit hacerle un Split `value.split(',');` pero si la accesibilidad es importante mejor utiliza un select con el parámetro multiple

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocupas hacer es concatenar al valor anterior con el nuevo valor.

`$("#pcom").val($("#pcom").val() + precio_compra);`

Pero tambien deberias agregar el codigo de `#precioc` para saber que contiene.

Comment: Ok, editate el post, pero el #precioc es solo un input que mete precios, mi intención es que, mediante un boton "Agregar", pueda llenar un vector de (cualquier cosa) y asignarlo aun html para rescatarlo después con otro boton Submit.

Comment: Segui tu consejo, pero digamos que ingreso un 1, le doy a agregar y me guarda otro 1, al final en la BD llega un 11.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta anterior está bastante completa, si deseas también puedes ocupar una variable creada en javascript del lado del front para almacenar el valor de cada input y a traves de un evento (cualquiera que desees ocupar) capture cada input y lo asigne a la variable que creaste, puede ser un array o un string (esto no importa mucho puesto que en el backend puedes convertir el string en array) y luego de tener todos los valores se asignen al input especifico. Por ejemplo:

```
<script>
let contenedorInputs = ''
let botonQueAgrega = document.querySelector('#bottonParaAgregar')

botonQueAgrega.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    //suponiendo que tienes 4 inputs dónde uno de estos va tomar los valores 
    //del resto usaras un querySelectorAll para rescatar todos esos inputs

    let inputs = querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      //la condición es para evitar que cualquier input vacío se agregue a la cadena
      if(!input.value == '') contenedorInputs += input.value + ','
    })

//ahora seleciona el input de tipo 'select' y asigna los valores capturados.
let inputSelect = querySelectorAll('input[type=select]')
inputSelect.value = contenedorInputs
    
})

</script>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <label for="stock">Precio</label>
    <input type="text" name="precioc" class="form-control" id="precioc">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5">
    <label for="cant">PRUEBA</label>
    <input type="select" name="pcom[]" class="form-control" id="pcom">
</div>
```

Espero te pueda servir :)

Comment: Sobre la respuesta anterior a la tuya, digamos que despues de ingresar dos veces el valor 1, en la bd me guarda un 11.

Comment: Sobre la tuya, no la termine de entender la verdad.